# I can't choose the set of 3 chemicals with each of which Si will react (out of 5 possible sets)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reactivity

This is one of the questions used in the [Russian State Chemistry Exam](https://ege.yandex.ru/chemistry/). One needs to select the set of chemicals in the second column such that **each of them** would react with the element or chemical in the the first column.

I mean, it should react with **each** element in the set in order for that set to be suitable.

> [image: Russian state chemistry exam question]

It seems to me that $\ce{Si}$ has no suitable set among those five.

It does not react with $\ce{Na2CO3}$ (that excludes set 1), with $\ce{HCl}$ (set 2), with$\ce{MgO}$ (set 3), with $\ce{H2SO4}$ (set 4) and with$\ce{Al(OH)3}$ (set 5).

I used Chemguide and a [Russian school curriculum-based website](https://sites.google.com/site/himulacom/zvonok-na-urok/9-klass---vtoroj-god-obucenia/urok-no42-kremnij-i-ego-soedinenia-steklo-cement) to refresh my memory of $\ce{Si}$ activity.

Am I wrong in regard of any of the five chemicals? Maybe it will react with $\ce{MgO}$, for instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\ce{Si}$ *does* in fact react with $\ce{HF}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$. The reactions would be:

$$\ce{Si + 4HF -> SiF4 + 2H2}$$

$$\ce{Si + 4NaOH -> Na4SiO4 + 2H2}$$

$$\ce{Si + 2MgO -> SiO2 + 2Mg}$$

You can conclude these, since $\ce{SiO2}$ is quite stable, and also reacts with $\ce{HF}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$ (You may have heard that $\ce{HF}$ dissolves glass), so definitely $\ce{Si}$ will react way better than $\ce{SiO2}$.

Comment: Yes, but it does not react with MgO, and that excludes set 3.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention its reaction with MgO, I'll add it now.

Comment: I have added the reaction, the one with $\ce{MgO}$ is also called the **Pidgeon Process**. More about it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgeon_process

Comment: Thank you! I knew that it reacts with Mg to produce MgO so I assumed the reverse reaction was unlikely.

Comment: I have edited your post with MathJax. You can learn how to use MathJax to write chemical equations here:https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here

Answer (score 3):

Silicon also react with the chemicals from set 2.

$$\ce{Si + 3HCl ->[300°C] SiHCl3 + H2}$$
$$\ce{Si + O2 ->[>900°C] SiO2}$$
$$\ce{Si + 2Cl2 ->[300°C] SiCl4}$$

Maybe you doubted the reaction between silicon and hydrogen chloride forming [trichlorosilane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichlorosilane).

Source of reactions: [webelements.com](https://www.webelements.com/silicon/chemistry.html)